# i am trying to read values through web usb in new chrome version but it is showing DOMException: a transfer error has occurred

Tags: google-chrome, webusb

I am trying to read values through `webusb` to my app in chrome version(89,90,91,92), but it is showing an error [(see screen shot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7QLQ.png).

Please help me to resolve this error. In a previous version I have used new usb backend disable option to resolve this issue but now it is removed in updated chrome versions(89,90,91,92).

Answer (score 0):

For a Prolific USB serial converter I recommend using the [Web Serial API](https://web.dev/serial/) instead of the WebUSB API because it is designed to interface with serial devices without any configuration changes. If this was working for you in the past on Windows then I assume that you have used a tool like [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) to replace the Prolific driver with the WinUSB driver. Please check in Device Manager that the device has the WinUSB.sys driver loaded and not some other driver.

When you see transfer failure you can get more detailed diagnostics from the log in chrome://device-log.

Comment: the web serial api only works for serial ports or we can use it to read usb devices. beacause while reading usb devices using web serial api it showing empty devices list.

Comment: The Web Serial API will work for any serial port, including USB devices which create a virtual serial port assuming that the appropriate driver is loaded. If the device list is empty then either the driver does not create a serial port entry or the driver is not loaded. If you are sure you want to continue using the WebUSB API for this device we can try to diagnose the cause of the transfer error. The first place to start as mentioned in my original answer is to make sure that the WinUSB.sys driver is loaded and to check chrome://device-log for a more detailed diagnostic message.